Imbalanced dataset and binary classification
In my dataset there are 31657 data and each has a binary output( 1 or 0).
The problem is that the output 1 occurs only 886/31657 times, while 0 occurs 30771/31657 times.
Since my dataset is imbalanced,the validation and the training sets are also imbalanced because they are taken randomly in the LSTM neural network.
I tried to assign a weight to each output (1 for output 0 and 5 for output 1), but is there a specific method for assigning these weights?
I also tried to divide the validation and training sets in a balanced way (considering the weights) but the results are not good
What could I do?
thank you

Welcome to CV, Daniela.  Have you thought of reading some of our many posts on this subject?  It's likely you will find a good answer has already appeared.
